# Net force for circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, centripetal-force

So today my physics teacher was telling us that the net force when discussing circular motion was actually the centripetal force. He didn't go further and I would like to know if there's any proof to this claim. The more rigorous the better.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force#Uniform_circular_motion

Answer (score 3):

If you whirl a ball on a string over your head, you are always throwing away the ball. But the ball is not getting thrown because a force is drawing the ball towards your hand via string. This force is called **centripetal force**. If force exists, definitely acceleration exists. This acceleration is **centripetal acceleration**. Centripetal acceleration and centripetal fore are vector quantities and is always towards center of circular motion.

For given velocity and radius of circular motion,
[Calculate centripetal force](http://calculatephysics.com/CentripetalForce.html)
[Calculate centripetal acceleration](http://calculatephysics.com/CentripetalAcceleration.html)

Answer (score 2):

If a particle is following a circular path of radius $R$ in a certain frame of reference, the position vector can be written $$\vec{r}=R\cos\theta\hat{i}+R\sin\theta\hat{j},$$
where $\theta$ is the angle measured with respect to the $x$ axis.

If the motion is *uniform* circular motion, the angular speed and the tangential speed are constant. For an angular speed of $\omega$ the angle (assuming $\theta=0$ at $t=0$ is given by $$\theta=\omega t.$$

The total acceleration in this situation will be given by the second time derivative of $\vec{r}$:
$$\vec{a}=\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 \vec{r}}{\mathrm{d}t^2}=-\omega^2\vec{r}.$$

The direction of this acceleration is toward the center of the circle and has magnitude $\omega^2|\vec{r}|=\omega^2 R.$ The tangential speed is  $v_{tan}=\omega R$, so we finally see the familiar form of centripetal acceleration magnitude: $$a_c=\frac{v_{tan}^2}{R^2}R = \frac{v_{tan}^2}{R^2}.$$

According to Newton's second law, the acceleration of a particle is equal to the net force divided by the mass of the particle which gives us the relationship $$F_{net}=m\left(\frac{v_{tan}^2}{R^2}\right)=\Large\Sigma_{j}\large\vec{F}_j.$$

Notice that there is *not* one particular force which is **the** centripetal force. A sum of forces produces the centripetal acceleration behavior.

Comment: <Notice that there is not one particular force which is the centripetal force. A sum of forces produces the centripetal acceleration behavior.>  but in your above analysis no other force -other than centripetal force has been considered -so how this statement can be understood.

Comment: @drvrm Look at my last equation.  The **net** force is what provides the acceleration. It could be composed of a combination of forces: gravity, tension, static friction, a spring.  The acceleration is what is centripetal.  I never considered a specific force, or even a single force.

Comment: sorry , i missed that last point  of different agency contributing to the centripetal acceleration-but net force i s centripetal force

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you did not call the net force directed towards the centre of the circle the centripetal force but rather say "the net force towards the centre of the circle produces the centripetal acceleration".

When there is a satellite orbiting the Earth the net force on the satellite is $\frac{GMm}{r^2}$.  This is the resultant of all the forces of gravitational attraction between individual atoms in the Earth and the individual atoms in the satellite.  That (net) gravitational attractive force on the satellite due to the Earth causes the centripetal acceleration.

The idea of centripetal force being a different/extra force from the ones which are acting seems to cause a lot of confusion.